# Show that the sum of error terms in the Law of Total Probability approach zero

Tags: probability, asymptotics

I'm trying to calculate a sequence of probabilities, using the Law of Total Probability. It looks something like this:

$$ P(X_n = x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} a_k^{(n)} \left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)\right).$$

Each of the summands contains a relative error of $O(1/n)$.

**Question:** how to show that the sum of the error terms, $\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} a_k^{(n)} O\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)$, is negligible ?
Clearly,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} a_k^{(n)} O\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} O\left(\frac{1}{n} \right),$$
but the sum on the RHS can (theoretically) be unbounded, as $n\to \infty$.

I have to factor in the fact that I'm summing probabilities, and the sum is therefore bounded above by $1$, but how to do that?

Comment: Can we say, that $a_k^{(n)}$ are bounded against $n$?

Comment: Sure. They are probabilities, and thus bounded above by $1$. More than that, they happen to also be $O(1/n)$.

Comment: So $a_k^{(n)} O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. But let me ask how you understand upper bound of sum?

Comment: You mean $a_k^{(n)} O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Comment: No. I mean $C \cdot O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for any constant/bounded against $n$. What about upper bound of sum?

Comment: There exists a $K$ such that for every $n$, the sum is less than $K$.

Comment: So do you have bounded amount of members in sum?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109811/discussion-between-teddy-and-zkutch).

Answer (score 0):

If
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_k}{\frac{1}{n}} = c_1\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{r_k}{\frac{1}{n}} = c_2
$$
you get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}}a_k(1 \pm r_k) \leq\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{c_1}{n}(1+ \frac{c_2}{n}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{c_1}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{c_1 c_2}{n^2} = \frac{c_1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{c_1 c_2}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} = O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})
$$
So your sum on the right is of the order $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

Comment: The problem with this solution is that $a_k < c_1/n$ only for large enough $n$. So the inequality is unjustified.